# Avoiding null comparisons in where clause

Tags: sql-server, performance, null, isnull, query-performance

It's my impression that comparing to null limits the use of an index. We had a DBA come in and that statement was part of his notes, however no better example was given.

If that statement is true, what is a better way to write the following?

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.DpdRoute 
    WHERE DestinationCountry =@COUNTRY 
    AND (  (BeginPostCode IS NULL      AND ENDPOSTCODE IS NULL) 
        OR (BeginPostCode  = @POSTCODE AND ENDPOSTCODE IS NULL)
        OR (BeginPostCode IS NULL      AND ENDPOSTCODE  = @POSTCODE)
        OR (BeginPostCode <= @POSTCODE AND ENDPOSTCODE >= @POSTCODE))
```

I'm looking for a list of routes, for a given country where a postcode is either within a range of postcodes, equal to the min or max post code, or the min or max post codes are both null.

How does one "not compare to null" when the comparison is specifically about "nulls"?

Comment: Give this a read: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: It's not about NULLs, it's about ORs.

Comment: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) by Erland Sommarskog is a very good comprehensive article on this topic. In essence, in SQL Server 2008+ this type of query usually should have `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` hint to generate a good plan for all possible values of parameters.

Comment: This isn't dynamic search. There is no conditional logic checking if the **variable** is null and if so doing something different. It is checking if the `column` is null.

Comment: Can the query return more than 1 rows or is it guaranteed to return max 1 row always?

Comment: https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/

Answer (score 4):

If you have an index on `DestinationCountry,BeginPostCode,ENDPOSTCODE` then your original query seeks into the `DestinationCountry` part but no further.

You may find better performance rewriting as an `UNION ALL` if you have that index.

The below can seek into non overlapping parts of this index.

- An exact seek on `(DestinationCountry, BeginPostCode, ENDPOSTCODE)` =  `(@COUNTRY,NULL, NULL)`
- An exact seek on `(DestinationCountry, BeginPostCode, ENDPOSTCODE)` =  `(@COUNTRY,NULL,  @POSTCODE)`
- An equality seek on `(DestinationCountry)` =  `(@COUNTRY)` and then a range seek on the secondary key `BeginPostCode <= @POSTCODE` with a residual predicate on all rows that match.

__

```
WITH Country
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   dbo.DpdRoute
         WHERE  DestinationCountry = @COUNTRY) 
SELECT *
FROM   Country
WHERE  BeginPostCode IS NULL
       AND ENDPOSTCODE IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   Country
WHERE  BeginPostCode IS NULL
       AND ENDPOSTCODE = @POSTCODE
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   Country
WHERE  BeginPostCode <= @POSTCODE
       AND ( ENDPOSTCODE >= @POSTCODE
              OR ( BeginPostCode = @POSTCODE
                   AND ENDPOSTCODE IS NULL ) );
```

[image]

Comment: Don't have time for an answer, and even less for performance tests/analysis, but do you think this could have any good potential: `SELECT ... WHERE EXISTS (SELECT BeginPostCode, ENDPOSTCODE INTERSECT (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (NULL, NULL), (NULL, @PostCode), (@PostCode, NULL), (@PostCode, @PostCode)) AS v (BPC, EPC)) UNION ALL SELECT ... WHERE BeginPostCode < @PostCode AND ENDPOSTCODE > @PostCode`?

Comment: @AndriyM - I tried this already with disappointing results https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNnma.png (only seeks into the country and residual predicate on the rest)

Comment: @AndriyM - you mean this? The selected seek in the image again only seeks on the first key https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCh35.png and then has a residual predicate against all rows matching a country

Comment: Yes, that one, thanks! Two seeks instead of three, not too much of a gain, I guess. Unless they have a lot of posts.

Comment: @AndriyM - They get that seek on country with their original query. The advantage if there is one in the `UNION ALL` is that they can levarage the second and third key columns and not have to process all rows for a country. If they have many rows for a country and pass a low value for `@POSTCODE` this could potentially be beneficial. As all rows for the country where `BeginPostCode > @POSTCODE` don't have to be seeked.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the added piece to your comment preceding my last reply. That's something to consider. Thanks again.

Comment: What a nice answer, @MartinSmith - I never would have thought of using a UNION on a CTE.  Nice work!

Comment: @MaxVernon - thanks. Hopefully you'll be able to reuse your answer on a dynamic search one soon!

Answer (score 0):

```
(    (BeginPostCode IS NULL      AND ENDPOSTCODE IS NULL) 
  OR (BeginPostCode  = @POSTCODE AND ENDPOSTCODE IS NULL)
  OR (BeginPostCode IS NULL      AND ENDPOSTCODE  = @POSTCODE)
  OR (BeginPostCode <= @POSTCODE AND ENDPOSTCODE >= @POSTCODE) 
)
```

That might be the same as

```
    isnull(BeginPostCode, @POSTCODE) <= @POSTCODE 
and isnull(ENDPOSTCODE,   @POSTCODE) >= @POSTCODE
```

I could be wrong. I think every condition that need to pass does pass.
Not sure if something that should fail will get through.

It fails on `BeginPostCode IS NULL and ENDPOSTCODE >= @POSTCODE`

This might work

```
    (     isnull(BeginPostCode, @POSTCODE) = @POSTCODE 
      and isnull(ENDPOSTCODE,   @POSTCODE) = @POSTCODE ) 
 OR ( BeginPostCode <= @POSTCODE AND ENDPOSTCODE >= @POSTCODE )
```